# How to sync a directory with Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I have a local directory that I want to sync onto the remote server. I have this provider:

```
resource "null_resource" "test" {
  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "deploy"
    host        = "${MYHOST}"
    port        = 22
    private_key = "${MYKEY}"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "mkdir -p /tmp/hello && touch /tmp/hello/world"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = ["mkdir -p /tmp/mytest"]
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "/tmp/hello"
    destination = "/tmp/mytest/hello"
  }
}
```

This works first time. The directory now exists on the remote server.

```
$ find /tmp/mytest
/tmp/mytest
/tmp/mytest/hello
/tmp/mytest/hello/world
```

But if I taint and re-apply the resource, second time round the remote directory exists, and the directory is synced *inside*:

```
$ find /tmp/mytest
/tmp/mytest
/tmp/mytest/hello
/tmp/mytest/hello/hello
/tmp/mytest/hello/hello/world
/tmp/mytest/hello/world
```

I can work round this by deleting the whole directory tree remotely before syncing, but that seems inelegant, possibly inefficient and potentially error-prone.

Is there standard solution to repeatedly syncing a directory?

Answer (score 0):

This is addressed in the file provisioner documentation:

> Next, the existence of a trailing slash on the source path will determine whether the directory name will be embedded within the destination, or whether the destination will be created. An example explains this best:
>
> If the source is /foo (no trailing slash), and the destination is /tmp, then the contents of /foo on the local machine will be uploaded to /tmp/foo on the remote machine. The foo directory on the remote machine will be created by Terraform.
>
> If the source, however, is /foo/ (a trailing slash is present), and the destination is /tmp, then the contents of /foo will be uploaded directly into /tmp directly.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/file.html

Comment: Thanks, however there are no trailing slashes in my example. As far as I can tell, the docs don't match what actually happens.

Comment: No it doesnt match. I cant make it work